# What is the React JS equivalent of map function for objects? (Closed)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

I am new to React, so please bear with me as I unveil my question. I am trying to handle API calls so that I can display the returned JSON files on HTML tables. So far I have been using the map function in order to properly assign keys and values to the table cells.

One thing I noticed almost right away, which the internet search could not help me with, was that the map function was useful and functional to me so long as the returned data of a JSON file were inside square brackets ..**[]**.., possibly leading to them being items inside a table. See below:

```
[
    {
        "id_1": 0,
        "id_2": 1,
        "id_3": 30,
        "id_4": 9,
        "id_5": 0,
        "id_6": "Marty",
        "id_7": "111-111-1111",
        "location": "Algiers",
        "id_0": 0
    }
]
```

Once I stumbled upon a JSON file, the data of which were not inside square brackets but just regular curly brackets ..**{}**.. it appeared that the map function no longer made sense. See below:

```
{
    "id_1": 1,
    "whatever_id": 1,
    "whatever_name": "Blah",
    "id_0": 0
}
```

I would like to give notice to the fact that once the react app compiles and localhost:**** fires up, data are not shown in the form of a table. However, I can see that the API was successfully called upon by inspecting the app and hitting the network tab to check the contents of the returned call. At this point I am giving a sample of what the table code looks like:

```
<table className='in-line'>
        <thead>
          {(items.length > 0) ? items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <Fragment key={index}>
                <tr><th>Blah blah 1</th><td>{item.id_1}</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Blah blah 2</th><td>{item.id_2.nameless_id}</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Name</th><td>{item.id_2.name}</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Blah blah 3</th><td>{item.id_2.wired_id}</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Update</th><td>{item.update}</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Record</th><td>{item.record}</td></tr>
              </Fragment>
            );
          }) : <tr><td colSpan='5'>Data Loading...</td></tr>}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

The `<th>` and `<td>` contents are random just to indicate how the table is formed. In its current state it can render a JSON file that is within square brackets, but not a JSON file within curly brackets only.

---

**UPDATE#1:** I am now including my code so far, because I cannot seem to make it work. I have also omitted certain details for security reasons.

***App.js***

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Table from "./components/BasicTable";

const App = () => {
    
    const [droplets, setDroplets] = useState([]);
    const handleClick = () => { 
        const api = "https://1...8"
        
        const token = 'e...w'

        fetch(api, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => JSON.parse(setDroplets(response)))
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Table droplets={droplets} handleClick={handleClick}/>
        </div>
    );
};
export default App;
```

***Table.js***

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import "./table.css";

const Table = ({ droplets, handleClick }) => {

  return (
    <div className='parent'>
      <table className='in-line'>
        <thead>
          {(droplets.length > 0) ?
            (Object.values(droplets).map((droplet, index) => {
              return (
                <Fragment key={index}>
                  <tr><th>Lamp Fault</th><td>{droplet.lampFault}</td></tr>
                  <tr><th>Autonomy</th><td>{droplet.autonomy}</td></tr>
                            ...............................
                            ...............................
                            ...............................
                  <tr><th>Fully Charged</th><td>{droplet.fullyCharged}</td></tr>
                </Fragment>
              );
            })) : <tr><td colSpan='5'>Loading...</td></tr>}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      <div className='button-container'>
        <button className='button-style' onClick={handleClick}>LOAD DATA</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Table;
```

***Question:*** Forgive me, but I fail to see how the current code, perhaps inside the fetch function and/or inside the table, should be changed, so any hints will definitely be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE#2:** It turned out that the returned JSON file was already an object, so there was no need to parse it. Also, the .map function inside the table was unnecessary once a couple of model objects for the JSON file were created. I am adding an instance of two of the models, as well as the updated Table.js code.

***LumStatus.js***

```
import WirelessLum from './WirelessLum'

function LumStatus() {
    this.pkid = 0,
    this.wirelessLumid = 0,
    this.lastStatRecStamp = "",
    ..................
    ..................
    ..................
    this.wVersion = "",
    this.tmpLampTestMade = 0,
    WirelessLum
}
export default LumStatus
```

***WirelessLum.js***

```
function WirelessLum() {
    this.pkid = 0,
    this.otherid = 0,
    this.simpSignid = 0,
    ..................
    ..................
    ..................
    this.lumModel = null,
    this.lumStat = []
}
export default WirelessLum
```

***Table.js (updated)***

```
const BasicTable = ({ droplets, handleClick, LumStatus, WirelessLum }) => {

    return (
        <div className='parent'>
            <table className='in-line'>
                <thead>
                    <Fragment>
                        <tr><th>Wireless Luminaire ID</th><td {droplets.wirelessLumid}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>PKID</th><td>{droplets.wirelessLum && droplets.wirelessLum.pkid}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Lamp Name</th><td>{droplets.wirelessLum && droplets.wirelessLum.name}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Registered</th><td>{droplets.wirelessLum && droplets.wirelessLum.registered}</td></tr>
                             ......................................
                             ......................................
                             ......................................
                        <tr><th>Lamp Fault</th><td {droplets.lampFault}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Lamp Current</th><td {droplets.lampCurrent}</td></tr>
                    </Fragment>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className='button-container'>
                <button className='button-style' onClick={handleClick}>LOAD DATA</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default BasicTable;
```

Since the creation of models, it seemed less complicated and more useful to remove the .map function and halt the conversion from object to array. A simple dot notation was enough to return a populated table.

When it came to nested objects inside the JSON file, because of the asynchronous API call, they were being declared undefined, most likely due to them being rendered before the entirety of the JSON info. What did seem to work was conditionally rendering the nested objects in the table: `{droplets.wirelessLum && droplets.wirelessLum.pkid}`

I would like to thank everyone for their contribution! Cheers!

Comment: `Object.entries(youObject).map()`
this will returns an array of [key, value]

Comment: [Map is for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will give you an array you can map from the object.

Comment: Thank you for your help so much! I have edited the original question so that it may become clearer as to how I should proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is an array
`{}` is an object

`map` belongs to arrays.
You can take a look at object prototype if you want to "convert" them into arrays.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

**As an example:**

if you want to get all the values and don't care about the key :

```js
Object.values(items).map(value => { ... })
```

if you only want the keys and don't care about the value :

```js
Object.keys(items).map(key => { ... })
```

if you want to need both key and value

```js
Object.entries(items).map(([key, value]) => {...})
```

Comment: It seems that I need both the key and value each time. I practically replaced `items.map((item, index) => { ... })` with your suggestion: `Object.entries(items).map(([index, item]) => { ... }`
How will this line for example be converted to match the change from map to Object.entries? `<tr><th>Update</th><td>{item.update}</td></tr>` 
Console still catches the JSON data, but the table is having a hard time being rendered.

Comment: what is the exact format of `items` ?

Comment: `items` are the values of the JSON field names, and they can be strings, booleans, integers or empty arrays, by the looks of the original JSON file.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time! I have now included all relevant code, to make pinpointing faults easier and faster.

Comment: @AsteriosKalogeras still not clear for me if you get an array or object at the end. try to console log the exact same thing that you send in your state.

According to what I see on your raw json, you have an array of 1 containing an object. if so you would need to do this instead : ```.then((response) => JSON.parse(setDroplets(response[0])))```

Comment: It turns out, after following your suggestion, that the `json` file was an object all along, so there was no need to be parsed. Basic dot notation inside the table did the job, after I created a model object to assign to the state variable. When this was done, I had to deal with the API's asynchronous call that messed with the rendering of the `json`'s nested items. Albeit a bit inelegantly done, but I will update the final `Table.js` code for all to see. Thanks again! I am closing this question now.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a [string-based data interchange format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

To map over each property of the objects represented in your JSON, first you need to parse the JSON string into an object using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Your JSON parses into an array of objects.

In order to use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (read this as 'array dot prototype dot map') on each object in your array, you need to create an array from the properties on each object. [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) will help with this. For completeness, JS also has a [`for..in` loop construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) that will enumerate all the enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by Strings (ie. not Symbols), including inherited properties, but `for...in` is probably not what you want.

The following React implementation displays a button that when pressed makes an API call, waits for it, and then sends the data for display to a simple `Table` React component. The source data is initially in the form of a JSON string.

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 10pt;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
button {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

const fakeDelay = (ms = 2500) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms))

const Table = ({ data = [] }) => {  
    return (
      <table>
        {
          !(data.length) 
            ? <tr><td>Nothing to show!</td></tr>
            : data.map((row) => 
              <tr>
                {Object.values(row).map((cell) => <td>{cell}</td>)}
              </tr>)
        }
      </table>     
    )
}

const App = () => {
  const URL = 'https://mocki.io/v1/37eb5d4d-2dc7-4954-9043-c315079bda3e'
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([])

  const go = async () => {
    await fakeDelay()
    setData(await (await fetch(URL)).json())
  }
  
  return <div><button onClick={go}>Fetch data for table</button> <Table data={data}/></div>
}  

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.querySelector('main')
)
</script>
<main></main>
```

Comment: I would like to thank you, as your suggestion has prompted me to look some things up and further my view on this thing. I have now included all relevant code, if you could spare some moments to give it another hint or two!